# createTransferable for JLabel or JPanel does not fire

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jpanel, jlabel

Scaled back a sample I found to test working with `JPanel` and `JLabel`.

A new `TransferHandler` object is created for the `createTransferable()` call for both `JPanel` and `JLabel`.

Since there is no `setDraggable` method so I included the `exportAsDrag` (which is what I think is required if the object doesn't have the `setDraggable` method).

Although `createTransferable(`) returns `null` and won't really do anything I should at least get the `println` executed, but the code doesn't seem to enter that section which means neither the panel or label is seen as a draggable object.

What is the missing step to get this to be seen as a draggable object. 
And if you have a panel with a bunch of labels is it recommended to make the panel draggable and sort out which label or make each individual label draggable?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class DnDTransferableTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DnDTransferableTest();
}

public DnDTransferableTest() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(new TestPane());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;

    public TestPane() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        label1 = new JLabel("Drag Me.");
        add(label1, gbc);

        label2 = new JLabel("Drag Me too.");
        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        add(label2, gbc);

        setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public Transferable createTransferable(final JComponent c)
            {
                System.out.println("Inside Panel : createTransferable");
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getSourceActions(final JComponent c)
            {
                System.out.println("Inside Panel : getSourceActions()");
                return COPY;
            }

            @Override
            public void exportAsDrag(final JComponent comp, final InputEvent e,  final int action)
            {
                System.out.println("Inside Panel : getSourceActions()");
                  super.exportAsDrag(comp, e, action);
            }
        });

        label1.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public Transferable createTransferable(final JComponent c)
            {
                System.out.println("Inside Label : createTransferable");
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getSourceActions(final JComponent c)
            {
                System.out.println("Inside Label : getSourceActions()");
                return COPY;
            }

            @Override
            public void exportAsDrag(final JComponent comp, final InputEvent e,  final int action)
            {
                System.out.println("Inside Label : getSourceActions()");
                  super.exportAsDrag(comp, e, action);
            }
        });

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to have the user drag specifically? An image? A component?

Comment: My actual object is way more involved, right now I am just trying to get off the ground and understand why these items are not recognized as draggable. I am looking for a more direct route and not having to implement any mouse listeners.

Comment: I think that you will need a MouseListener to allow the JLabel to accept a drag gesture since it does not have a `setDragEnabled(...)` method.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you will need a MouseListener to allow the JLabel to accept a drag gesture since it does not have a `setDragEnabled(...)` method.

To use a MouseListener with your DnD:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;

public class DnDTransferableTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new DnDTransferableTest();
   }

   public DnDTransferableTest() {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(new TestPane());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }

   public class TestPane extends JPanel {

      private JLabel label3;
      private JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);

      public TestPane() {
         label3 = new JLabel("Fubars Rule!");
         add(label3);
         add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(35));
         add(textField);

         label3.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));
         label3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mEvt) {
               JComponent component = (JComponent) mEvt.getSource();
               TransferHandler tHandler = component.getTransferHandler();
               tHandler.exportAsDrag(component, mEvt, TransferHandler.COPY);
            }
         });
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. Your usage of the exportAsDrag makes sense. As suspected, that method is used when setDragEnabled(...) is not available. The one problem is my implementation was off base.

Comment: Added the mouse listener and received an exception then noticed the setTransferHandler() still needed to be set. Did that and that works since it is designed for "text". I then switched to using my anonymous class which overrides the createTransferable () and now the method fires. Cool!!!